# Select from SUM() of multiple columns and join in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table called DETAILS which has 5 numeric columns DETAILS(id, key2, key3, num1, num2, num3, num4, num5). Combination of id, key2 and key3 is the primary key. Each id may have multiple rows.

My requirement is to get top 10 SUM values of each column grouped by id as below.

```
select   id
        ,sum(num1) val1
 from details   
group by id
order by sum(num1) desc nulls last
limit 10;

select   id
        ,sum(num2) val2
 from details  
group by id
order by sum(num2) desc nulls last
limit 10;

select   id
        ,sum(num3) val3
 from details   
group by id
order by sum(num3) desc nulls last
limit 10;

select   id
        ,sum(num4) val4
 from details   
group by id
order by sum(num4) desc nulls last
limit 10;

select   id
        ,sum(num5) val5
 from details
group by id
order by sum(num5) desc nulls last
limit 10;
```

I need the above results to be combined based on the id as below

```
id, sum(num1), sum(num2), sum(num3), sum(num4), sum(num5)
```

Lets say
the first query returns

```
[{id: 1, val1: 50}, {id: 2, val1: 60}, {id: 3, val1: 70}]
```

the second query returns

```
[{id: 3, val2: 150}, {id: 4, val2: 160}, {id: 3, val2: 170}]
```

The result should be

```
[
{id: 1, val1: 50, val2: null}, 
{id: 2, val1: 60, val2: null}, 
{id: 3, val1: 70, val2: 150},
{id: 4, val1: null, val2: 160},
{id: 5, val1: null, val2: 170},
]
```

Is this possible with single query using join or something? If so how do I achieve this with a optimised query?

Comment: The ids of each of your 5 queries may be different. So what is your expected output?

Comment: @forpas To combine all the ids and get sum values for each of the columns resulted in each of the queries.

Comment: If the 1st query returns ids 1-10 and the 2nd returns ids 11-20 and so on how should they be combined? .

Comment: I don't understand how you combine if ids are different ? And if not then just put the sum into same query ? Or is there something you are not telling ?it's clear from your query that It's same table and same id in group by column

Comment: @forpas and Suithmohanty30 - I have updated my question with an example for better understanding.

Comment: @coder, Thanks for the update but I am still not convinced. I got your point but I doubt it can be done in a simpler way. I would further as you , is the source table same for all the query ? and if it is same then what is the issue if I do `sum(num1) as val1` and `sum(num2) val2` in the same query lets say for `id=3`, why it will not give the result like `{id: 3, val1: 70, val2: 150}` ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 - Yes, the source table is same for all the queries. I can't do simple sum() of all the columns because I need only the top 10 rows of each sum()

Comment: I don't want to put it as an answer until you check first but to provide an alternative way because of my understanding and not able to imagine the data , Could you check the last query of db<>fiddle if it works for you. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=04c202643eda9e4954f74f31c8e52e5f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want a FULL OUTER JOIN of all 5 queries:

```
with
  cte1 as (
    select id, sum(num1) val1 from details   
    group by id
    order by sum(num1) desc nulls last limit 10
  ),
  cte2 as (
    select id, sum(num2) val2 from details   
    group by id
    order by sum(num2) desc nulls last limit 10
  ),  
  cte3 as (
    select id, sum(num3) val3 from details   
    group by id
    order by sum(num3) desc nulls last limit 10
  ),  
  cte4 as (
    select id, sum(num4) val4 from details   
    group by id
    order by sum(num4) desc nulls last limit 10
  ),  
  cte5 as (
    select id, sum(num5) val5 from details   
    group by id
    order by sum(num5) desc nulls last limit 10
  )
select coalesce(c1.id, c2.id, c3.id, c4.id, c5.id) id,
       c1.val1, c2.val2, c3.val3, c4.val4, c5.val5
from cte1 c1
full outer join cte2 c2 on c2.id = c1.id
full outer join cte3 c3 on c3.id = c2.id
full outer join cte4 c4 on c4.id = c3.id
full outer join cte5 c5 on c5.id = c4.id
```