# Summarized table in postgreSQL for better performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, rdbms

I am using postgreSQL as my database. I have a table MASTER(A, B, C, D, N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, N6) where the primary key is (A, B, C, D) and N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, N6 are the numeric columns.

I have a query as below to get the summarized data of each A selected from each list in MASTERCOMB.

```
    SELECT MASTERCOM.A
    ,STATS.sumn1
    ,STATS.sumn2
    ,STATS.sumn3
    ,STATS.sumn4
    ,STATS.sumn5
    ,STATS.sumn6
 FROM (WITH 
 sum1 AS (SELECT A, SUM(N1) FROM MASTER WHERE B = $1 GROUP BY A ORDER BY SUM(N1) DESC LIMIT $2),
 sum2 AS (SELECT A, SUM(N2) FROM MASTER WHERE B = $1 GROUP BY A ORDER BY SUM(N2) DESC LIMIT $2),
 sum3 AS (SELECT A, SUM(N3) FROM MASTER WHERE B = $1 GROUP BY A ORDER BY SUM(N3) DESC LIMIT $2),
 sum4 AS (SELECT A, SUM(N4) FROM MASTER WHERE B = $1 GROUP BY A ORDER BY SUM(N4) DESC LIMIT $2),
 sum5 AS (SELECT A, SUM(N5) FROM MASTER WHERE B = $1 GROUP BY A ORDER BY SUM(N5) DESC LIMIT $2),
 sum6 AS (SELECT A, SUM(N6) FROM MASTER WHERE B = $1 GROUP BY A ORDER BY SUM(N6) DESC LIMIT $2)

SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(sum1.A, sum2.A, sum3.A, sum4.A, sum5.A, sum6.A) A
    FROM sum1
    FULL OUTER JOIN sum2 ON sum2.A = sum1.A
    FULL OUTER JOIN sum3 ON sum3.A = sum1.A
    FULL OUTER JOIN sum4 ON sum4.A = sum1.A
    FULL OUTER JOIN sum5 ON sum5.A = sum1.A
    FULL OUTER JOIN sum6 ON sum6.A = sum1.A) MASTERCOMB

LEFT JOIN (SELECT A 
            ,SUM(N1) sumn1
            ,SUM(N2) sumn2
            ,SUM(N3) sumn3
            ,SUM(N4) sumn4
            ,SUM(N5) sumn5
            ,SUM(N6 sumn6) 
        FROM MASTER WHERE B = $1 GROUP BY A) AS STATS
 ON STATS.A = MASTERCOMB.A
```

This is just one kind of query with B in the WHERE clause. I may have to query with different combinations like 'WHERE C = $3' OR 'WHERE D = $4'. In rare cases I may have to query with combinations of multiple conditions on B, C and D together;

As the table grows, the performance of the queries could drop. So I am thinking of two aproaches

**Approach #1:**

- Create Summary Tables SMRY_A_B, SMRY_A_C, SMRY_A_D
- On each insert, update and delete of MASTER table, SUM the values and insert/update/delete respective tables

**Approach #2:**

- Create a Summary table SMRY_A_B_C_D with primary key (A, B, C, D)
- On each insert, update and delete of MASTER table, SUM the values and insert/update/delete SMRY_A_B_C_D table

possible values for SMRY_A_B_C_D could be

```
(valA, valB, 'N/A', 'N/A', sumn1, sumn2, sumn3, sumn4, sumn5, sumn6) 
(valA, 'N/A, valC, 'N/A', sumn1, sumn2, sumn3, sumn4, sumn5, sumn6)
(valA, 'N/A, 'N/A', 'valD', sumn1, sumn2, sumn3, sumn4, sumn5, sumn6)
```

**Questions:**

- Which approach is better to go with?
- Should I not consider both the approaches and query from the master table itself? If so should I optimize the query?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help -- as would a *clear* explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Gordon Lindoff - I had posted a question on how to do a query which I posted in my question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64158435/6674171 . Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: . . I don't think that is the best answer to your question but you accepted that answer.  Perhaps you should ask a new question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In my question here I have asked should I optimise the above query. Do you think I should post it as a new question again?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I have posted a new question combining the previous one and the one which is posted here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64273807/group-by-and-summarise-the-result-in-postgresql