# Group by and summarise the result in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, group-by

I have a table called DETAILS which has 5 numeric columns DETAILS(id, key2, key3, num1, num2, num3, num4, num5). Combination of id, fk1, fk2, fk3, key2 and key3 is the primary key. Each id may have multiple rows as the primary key is the combination of (id, fk1, fk2, fk3)

My requirement is to get top 10 SUM values of each column grouped by id as below.

```
select   id
        ,sum(num1) val1
 from details   
group by id
order by sum(num1) desc nulls last
limit 10;

select   id, sum(num2) val2 from details where fk1=$1
group by id
order by sum(num2) desc nulls last
limit 10;

select   id, sum(num3) val3 from details where fk1=$1            
group by id
order by sum(num3) desc nulls last
limit 10;

select   id, sum(num4) val4 from details where fk1=$1              
group by id
order by sum(num4) desc nulls last
limit 10;

select   id,sum(num5) val5 from details where fk1=$1            
group by id
order by sum(num5) desc nulls last
limit 10;
```

I need the above results to be combined based on the id as below

```
id, sum(num1), sum(num2), sum(num3), sum(num4), sum(num5)
```

Lets say the first query returns

```
[{id: 1, val1: 70}, {id: 2, val1: 60}, {id: 3, val1: 50}]
```

the second query returns

```
[{id: 3, val2: 170}, {id: 4, val2: 160}, {id: 3, val2: 150}]
```

The result should be

```
[
{id: 1, val1: 50, val2: null}, 
{id: 2, val1: 60, val2: null}, 
{id: 3, val1: 70, val2: 150},
{id: 4, val1: null, val2: 160},
{id: 5, val1: null, val2: 170},
]
```

Is this possible with single query using join or something? If so how do I achieve this with a optimised query?

This is just one kind of query with fk1 in the WHERE clause. I may have to query **frequently** with conditions 'WHERE fk2 = $3' OR 'WHERE fk3 = $4'. In rare cases I may have to query with the combinations of multiple conditions on fk1, fk2 and fk3 together;

I am thinking of three approaches

**Approach #1:**

- Create Summary Tables smry_id_fk1, smry_id_fk2, smry_id_fk3
- On each insert, update and delete of DETAILS table, SUM the values and insert/update/delete respective new tables

**Approach #2:**

- Create a Summary table smry_id_fk1_fk2_fk3 with primary key (id, fk1, fk2, fk3)
- On each insert, update and delete of DETAILS table, SUM the values and insert/update/delete smry_id_fk1_fk2_fk3 table
  possible values for smry_id_fk1_fk2_fk3 could be

  (1, fk1value, 'N/A', 'N/A', 50, 60, 0, 0, 80)

  (2, 'N/A, fk2value, 'N/A', 150, 0, 160, 0, 170)

  (3, 'N/A, 'N/A', fk3value, 0, 0, 200, 210, 220)

**Approach #3:**

- Do not create any summarised tables. Use optimised query to get the results from DETAILS table itself.

**Questions:**

Which approach is better to go with? If Approach #3 is better, How do I achieve the desired result without compromising the performance?

Comment: You want the output in JSON

Comment: @AkhileshMishra - Yes

Comment: Please post some sample data and exact table structure, which will help to understand the question

Comment: To simplify your problem, you have to understand that in a combined result on the basis of ID column you can take the TOP 10 value based on only one column. Please specify it in the Question

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want ids and sums where the sums are in the top 10 overall.

This seems like aggregation with window functions:

```
select id,
       (case when seqnum_1 <= 10 then num1 end),
       (case when seqnum_2 <= 10 then num2 end),
       (case when seqnum_3 <= 10 then num3 end),
       (case when seqnum_4 <= 10 then num4 end),
       (case when seqnum_5 <= 10 then num5 end)
from (select id,
             sum(num1) as num1, sum(num2) as num2, sum(num3) as num3, sum(num4) as num4, sum(num5) as num5,
             row_number() over (order by sum(num1) nulls last) as seqnum_1,
             row_number() over (order by sum(num2) nulls last) as seqnum_2,
             row_number() over (order by sum(num3) nulls last) as seqnum_3,
             row_number() over (order by sum(num4) nulls last) as seqnum_4,
             row_number() over (order by sum(num5) nulls last) as seqnum_5
      from details d
      group by id
     ) d
where seqnum_1 <= 10 or seqnum_2 <= 10 or seqnum_3 <= 10 or seqnum_4 <= 10 or seqnum_5 <= 10;
```